# What is the meaning of "build on"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I read an article. But I have one difficult sentence to understand by myself.

That is "It is important to help students activate prior knowledge so they can build on it productively."

I couldn't understand it. What is the meaning of "build on"?

Comment: ***build on something***: To use something as a basis or foundation on which to develop something else: *The company built its hiring policy on the principle of fairness. The efficiency of our department is built on hard work.* http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/build+on

Comment: I got it. thanks you. In fact, I already found the dictionary, but I couldn't understand. However, I read what you wrote once again. I think I am understand. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Analogies of construction are common when speaking of education.  For example:

> It is important to begin a new academic program with a firm foundation, that is, a firm understanding of the fundamentals.

*Fundamentals* comes from the latin *fundare,* as does *foundation.*  This foundation is, of course, the material that the student has learned earlier, either through instruction or experience.

When one learns additional material in an academic program, therefore, one *builds on* the foundation.

Having said all that, I am compelled to add that the sentence would cause me to approach the article with great skepticism.  I am particularly wary of *activate prior knowledge,* which could almost certainly be phrased in a more meaningful way, but *build on it productively* also gives me pause.  What exactly does *productively* add to the sentence?